# Why PHP isn't display the last line of a file?

Tags: php

I would like to display the last line of an XML file, to see if it has a valid closing tag (e.g.  )

But my code doesn't diplay this last line.

```
$xml_input = file('whatever.xml');
$last line = trim(implode("", array_slice($xml_input, -1)));
echo "Last line is : " . $last_line;
```

The file exist at the same location where the PHP file is, and `file_get_contents` can read it (so no problem with access rights), and can display it using `echo`.

(Although it is strange that `file_get_contents` removes the xml tags, and displays only the information inside the tagged areas.)

Could you help me what the problem is with my code?

Comment: `Although it is strange that file_get_contents removes the xml tags, and display only the information inside the tagged areas` - If you're viewing the output in a web browser, then "view source".... PHP's file_get_contents() doesn't do this, your web browser does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fopen() and fread() to read the xml file like:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("whatever.xml", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// read untill the endand print that 
echo fread($myfile,filesize("whatever.xml"));
// you can save it in a variable and do string handling work.
fclose($myfile);
?>
```